# How do I Pass the 3 ids to next request in Jmeter after Extracting?

Tags: regex, jmeter

Sample view source of request

```
<html><input type="checkbox" class="abc" VId="2798997"
----
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" VId="2599787"
----
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" VId="2870713"
</html>
```

I am using Regular Expression as `VId="(.+?)"`

I am getting following output in the `RegXTest` view how to pass following three VIds to next request

```
Match count: 3
Match[1][0]=VId="2798997"
Match[1][1]=2798997
Match[2][0]=VId="2599787"
Match[2][1]=2599787
Match[3][0]=VId="2870713"
Match[3][1]=2870713
```

I am trying to pass like this `http:localhost:8080?Id=${Vid_g1},${Vid_g2},${Vid_g3}`
        but first value is passing as expected but remaining two values are not able to pass in request.please suggest me how to pass remaining two values in request.

Comment: `_g1`, `_g2` etc is notation for different matched groups. You only have one group. What is in your `Match Number` text box? I'm guessing 1?

Answer (score 0):

Set `Match Number` to `-1` and use this

```
http:localhost:8080?Id=${Vid_1},${Vid_2},${Vid_3}
```

Referenced from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

> refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0
>   refName_n, where n = 1,2,3 etc - the strings as generated by the template
>   refName_n_gm, where m=0,1,2 - the groups for match n
>   refName - always set to the default value
>   refName_gn - not set

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please click the tick mark and select as answer. Also consider clicking the up arrow to mark the answer as helpful.